# ?: Operator in VB to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, operators

I used an online converter to convert a piece of Visual Basics code to C#. The following code in VB:

```
Dim aset As New DataSet
aset = *code*
Dim str As String = ""
Dim str7 As String = ""
Dim str4 As String = ""
Dim str10 As String = ""

If (If(((str7 = str10) AndAlso (str7 <> "")), 1, 0) = 0) Then
    str7 = Conversions.ToString(aset.Tables.Item(0).Rows.Item(i).Item("PIN"))
End If
If (i <> 0) Then
    str4 = (str4 & " ,")
End If
    str4 = (str4 & str)
    str10 = str7
    i += 1
```

Was converted to the following C# code:

```
DataSet aset = new DataSet();
aset = *code*
string str = "";
string str7 = "";
string str4 = "";
string str10 = "";

if ((((str7 == str10) && (str7 != "")) ? 1 : 0 == 0))
{
    str7 = Conversions.ToString(aset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["PIN"]);
}
if ((i != 0))
{
    str4 = (str4 + " ,");
}
str4 = (str4 + str);
str10 = str7;
i += 1;
```

My questions deal with the ?: operator. I tried to do research on it, but it is still a little confusing to me. I receive an error in the C# version that says "Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and 'bool'." So when I changed the following C# piece of code:

```
if ((((str7 == str10) && (str7 != "")) ? 1 : 0 == 0))
```

to the following piece of code:

```
if ((((str7 == str10) && (str7 != "")) ? 1 == 0: 0 == 0)) //I changed '1' to '1 == 0'
```

The error seems to go away. However, I am not convinced that I correctly fixed the error to do what the program was doing in the VB code or if my solution altered what the purpose of that piece of code. Any help would be greatly appreciated to let me know if what I did was correct, or what I need to do.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The C# translation is wrong, and the VB is terrible.

```vb
If (If(((str7 = str10) AndAlso (str7 <> "")), 1, 0) = 0) Then
```

is

```vb
If If(((str7 = str10) AndAlso (str7 <> "")), 1, 0) = 0 Then
```

is

```vb
If Not ((str7 = str10) AndAlso (str7 <> "")) Then
```

is

```vb
If Not (str7 = str10) OrElse Not (str7 <> "") Then
```

is

```vb
If str7 <> str10 OrElse str7 = "" Then
```

. The equivalent C# is then `if (str7 != str10 || str7 == "")`.

Comment: can i have an amen brother

Comment: agreed, says this guy over here

Comment: I wonder why it was written in such a convoluted manner in the first place?

Comment: @user2366842: What’d you expect from someone who names their variables `str`, `str7`, `str4`, and `str10`? =)

Comment: What'd you expect from a decompiler?  This is stolen code.

Comment: Yeah, the original code was written by someone who was self taught.

Comment: @HansPassant This code isn't stolen and wasn't decompiled. The original author of the code was suppose to help me convert it before he quit.

Comment: No, this is clearly stolen code.  Your previous question made it unequivocal.  If you didn't steal it yourself then the "disgruntled employee" did it.  Clearly you need to notify your manager about it, companies take this *very* serious, the liability is enormous.

Comment: @HansPassant Can you please explain to me why it is stolen code then, instead of just saying it is? If it truly is stolen code then I will definitely talk to my manager, but I need to know why you think it is stolen in the first place.

Comment: Hmya, these kind of things have a funny way of biting back, all of a sudden *I'm* responsible for your company losing millions of dollars.  You got my professional opinion about it, dealing with it is the job of somebody who gets paid to deal with stuff like this.  Make sure that it is not you.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok, thank you for letting me know. Someone posted in the other question that brought this to your attention letting me know why. I will bring it to the attention of my boss.

Answer (score 2):

The conversion is missing a pair of parentheses. They are needed around the conditional operation, as the `==` operator has higher precedence:

```
if (((((str7 == str10) && (str7 != "")) ? 1 : 0) == 0))
```

Now the value of the conditional operation is `1` or `0`, just as in the original VB code.

Funny that the converter missed those parentheses, as it is very liberal with adding parentheses otherwise. Most of the parentheses in that line is not needed:

```
if ((str7 == str10 && str7 != "" ? 1 : 0) == 0)
```

The conditional operation is of course not needed at all, you can just check the condition in the `if` statement:

```
if (!(str7 == str10 && str7 != ""))
```

which is the same as:

```
if (str7 != str10 || str7 == "")
```